# How to use boosting in solrnet while using default query?

Tags: solr-boost

I am using SolrNet to do query on my default search field and not on any specific field. How can I use Boost on a specific field in that case? Below is the code snippet.

List filter = BuildQuerySingleLine(arrParams);

```
        var customer = solr.Query(parameters.SingleLineSearch, new QueryOptions
        {                
            FilterQueries  = filter,
            SpellCheck = new SpellCheckingParameters { Collate = true },
            OrderBy = new[] { new SortOrder("score", Order.DESC), SortOrder.Parse("score DESC") },
            StartOrCursor = new StartOrCursor.Start(parameters.StartIndex),
            Rows = parameters.NumberOfRows               

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I found the solution to this problem. For this I have used `dismax` request handler and passed the `qf` param value through SOLRNET.

With this you can pass the dynamic boost value to the SOLR query, on different fields.

```
var extraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "qt", "dismax" }, { "qf", "fieldName^1 FieldName^0.6" } };

var customer = solr.Query(parameters.SingleLineSearch, new QueryOptions
{                
                          
    StartOrCursor = new StartOrCursor.Start(parameters.StartIndex),
    Rows = parameters.NumberOfRows,
    }, 
    ExtraParams = extraParams
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this document: [Querying](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md#extraparams) and [The DisMax Query Parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html)

```
var extraParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

extraParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bq", "SomeQuery^10"));
extraParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bq", "SomeOtherQuery^10"));

var options new new QueryOptions();
options.ExtraParams = extraParams; //Since my List implements the right interface

solr.Query(myQuery, options)
```

the `bq` parameter should be used to boost the Query. @Abhijit Guha has an excellent answer, to use the same idea on the Field: qf (Query fields with optional boosts)

```
QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions
{
    ExtraParams = new KeyValuePair<string, string>[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("qt", "dismax"),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string>("qf", "title^1")
    },
    Rows = 10,
    Start = 0
};
```

Thank You!